# What is the efficiency of this code?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

```
public static int fxn1(int N){
       if(N == 0)
         return 0;
       return fx1(N/2) + fxn2(N) + fxn1(N/2);
}
```

The answer is `O(nlogn)`

I understand that fxn1 is `O(logn)` because of divide and conquer also `fxn2` is `O(n)`

so combine they all wouldn't it be `O(logn)+O(n)+O(nlogn) = O(nlogn^2)` ?

Please exaplain. Thanks

Comment: You haven't told us anything about `fx1` or `fxn2`.

Comment: what do you mean @PaulR I know that fx1 is logn fx2 is n so how can the answer come up with nlogn ?

Comment: You don't tell us anything about `fx1` in the question. It's also not clear what you mean by "understanding that `fxn2` is O(n)" ?

Comment: Note the recursion is the same as for mergesort, so [all these answers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/297160/why-is-mergesort-olog-n) are directly applicable. But `O(nlog(n^2)) = O(2nlogn) = O(nlogn)`, which would seemingly make this a duplicate of [What is a plain English explanation of “Big O” notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation) (big-O ignores constant factors), or off topic in the sense that explaining why `nlog(n^2) = 2nlogn` is purely mathematical and has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: You have `fxn1` and `fx1` in your code. Should those be the same? If not, you say "fxn1 is O(logn)", should that then be "fx1 is O(logn)" (because otherwise you indeed didn't say anything about `fx1`)?

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of the above recursion is given by - 
T(n) = T(n/2) + c1(log(n)) + c2(n)
which is also - 
T(n) = T(n/2) + c(n).
The above recurrence relation can be solved using the -

- Recursion Tree Method
- Master Theorem (specifically it is the second case of Master Theorem.)

Link for both  - http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-algorithm-set-4-master-method-solving-recurrences/.

Comment: and we are not dropping the lower big-oh and it would be only O(n^2) ?

Comment: @dyingStudent I didnot understand.